# I need a way to change Msys2 configuration to use Arch Linux AUR server mirrors instead of Msys2 ones

Tags: cygwin, archlinux, mingw-w64, msys2, pacman-package-manager

Because Msys2 sucks,

as mentioned above, I need to change its default server mirrors to point to Arch Linux Mingw-w64 AUR ones, and make it as the default one.

So when I issue some `pacman -S mingw-w64-*` it will download the package from Arch Linux Repository and not Msys2.

I need to use Msys2 only as a shell.

Msys2 Minwg-32/64 builds use Dwarf instead of SJLJ as exception model, and this is a very bad choice, because they don't catch exceptions from other DLLs that are built with other tool-chains, and the application will crash (For example Firebird 2).

Arch Linux is smart, and has chosen to use SJLJ as exception model for its Minwg-32/64 builds.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very unlikely to work. `pacman` for MSYS2 will download Windows PE binaries for your MSYS2 environment. `pacman` for Arch Linux is going to download Linux ELF binaries. You won't be able to run these on your Windows device.

You may be able to get what you want if you use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).